# Find 2 functions so that fg = 0

Tags: functions

The full question :

Find 2 functions $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$f,g \neq 0 $

so that $fg = 0$

The confusing part is the way it is written, as far as I can tell there is no product of anything other than $0$ which yields $0$, is there??

Perhaps they meant $f(g(x))$ in this question?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe there are two function, each of them is sometimes zero sometimes not (which is what they may mean by $f \ne 0$).

Comment: $f\neq 0$ only means "$f$ is not *always* zero", i.e. "there exists $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this: $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1& x>0 \\ 0 &x\le 0\end{cases}$$
 $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 0& x>0 \\ 1 &x\le 0\end{cases}$$

Note: If they meant $f(g(x))$, then you would still need $f$ to be zero somewhere.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same with rationals and irrationals. The idea is the same : split $\mathbb R$ into two sets.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)=\max(x,0)$$ $$g(x)=\min(x,0)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let X be the domain of f and g. Let f and g s.t. for any $x \in X$ we have $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$. Than f(x)g(x)=0 in X.